# AngularJS ng-repeat in this model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to know if it is possible to use ng-repeat in a model that look like this:

**Example Model:**

```
$scope.items = {
   item1:{[1,2,3,4,5]},
   item2:{[a,b,c,d,e]},
   item3:{[a1,b2,c3,d4,e5]}
};
```

The table should like this using ng-repeat:

```
-------------------------
| Item1 | Item2 | Item3 |
-------------------------
|   1   |   a   |   a1  |
|   2   |   b   |   b2  |
|   3   |   c   |   c3  |
|   4   |   d   |   d4  |
|   5   |   e   |   e5  |
-------------------------
```

If it is not possible using this model, can you please suggest some alernatives? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the data model like this

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        item1: 1,
        item2: 'a',
        item3: 'a1'
    }, {
        item1: 2,
        item2: 'b',
        item3: 'b2'
    }, {
        item1: 3,
        item2: 'c',
        item3: 'c3'
    }, ...];
}

<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <th>item1</th>
            <th>item2</th>
            <th>item3</th>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}
                <td>{{item.item1}}</td>
                <td>{{item.item2}}</td>
                <td>{{item.item3}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zn5Ty/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

If you can't/don't want to change your data structure, or don't know the number of keys, etc. ahead of time, you can also manipulate it on the fly. Here's an algorithm that works with objects with any number of keys, with arrays of any length (as long as every array has the same length):

```javascript
var results = { headers: [], values: [] };
angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
  results.headers.push(key);
  angular.forEach(value, function(inner, index) {
    results.values[index] = results.values[index] || [];
    results.values[index].push(inner);
  });
});
return results;
```

Once you have your transposed array, you can loop through it programmatically:

```html
<table ng-controller="DataController">
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="header in transposed.headers">{{header}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="ary in transposed.values">
    <td ng-repeat="item in ary">{{item}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a demo that re-transposes the `items` object each time it changes: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/BAGL5/

Comment: Thanks. I already changed my model but this may help me in the future. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.